Ito's Lemma application to debt process
If I have
$D(t)=E_t[\int_t^\infty exp(-r(u-t))dc_d(u)]$
where
$dc_d(u)=(1-\tau)P(u)du + (1-b)(1-\tau)P(u)sdW(u)$
and
$dP(t) = \mu P(t)dt + \sigma P(t)dW(t)$
How can I use Ito's Lemma to prove that value of $D(p)$ satisfies
$0.5\sigma^2p^2D_{pp}+\mu pD_p-rD+(1-\tau)p=0$

Should $\text{d}c_d(u)$ have a $u$ somewhere on the RHS? Also, what is $\sigma_p$ and $\mu_p$?

@msantama Sorry, corrected the typo
